# How to activate help() with a self created R package?

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

I am using `roxygen2` to build the documentation of a package that I created. The pdf documentation looks good but when I run `help(mypackage)` I get

```
No documentation for ‘mypackage’ in specified packages and libraries: 
you could try ‘??mypackage’
```

How can I make `help(mypackage)`to work?

Edit: the solution is exactly what @roman-luštrik said below :-)

Comment: link to gh/bb/rforge repo?

Comment: library(mypackage) was already loaded ;)

Comment: @hrbrmstr when the documentation is ok this will be publicly available

Comment: Just using roxygen2 doesn't get you the documentation. Did you actually build the help files using `roxygenize`? Or alternatively if you're actually using devtools did you use `document`?

Comment: you want help but gave no code or link to your pkg. help is unlikely, then

Comment: yes, I did that ... this is a weird issue 
I run document() and shift+cmd+d

Comment: This question is pretty clear. Not well formed (two questions in one), but still answerable and has room for improvement. @pachamaltese, please take a few seconds and take a [quick tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of how SO works (how to ask good questions and how to handle resolved questions).

Comment: I read again and now I have made it simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a [`<package-name>-package.R`](https://github.com/romunov/zvau/blob/master/R/zvau-package.R) file which is populated with `roxygen2` documentation and a single line of code: `NULL`.

```
#' Package contains functions used in daily work by our group for ecology at
#' Department of biology, Biotechnical faculty, University of Ljubljana.
#' 
#' So far the functions included in the package are:
#' \itemize{
#'   \item \code{\link{readClumpp}} Read result of Clumpp into a \code{data.frame}
#'   \item \code{\link{writeStructure}} Write a \code{genind} object to be analyzed using Structure
#'   \item \code{\link{writeGenePop}} Write a \code{genind} object to be analyzed using GENEPOP
#'   \item \code{\link{drawLoci}} Plot alleles using a list of loci
#' }
#' 
#' \tabular{ll}{
#' Package: \tab zvau\cr
#' Type: \tab Package\cr
#' Version: \tab 0.2\cr
#' Date: \tab 2015-02-11\cr
#' License: \tab GPL-2\cr
#' LazyData: \tab no\cr
#' }
#'
#' @author Roman Lustrik (\email{roman.lustrik@@emaildomain.com})(\email{mjelencic@@gmail.com})
#'
#' Maintainer: Roman Lustrik (\email{roman.lustrik@@emaildomain.com})
#' @name zvau-package
#' @import ggplot2
#' @aliases zvau
#' @docType package
#' @title Misc functions used by out group
#' @keywords package datasets
NULL
```

When I type `?zvau` or `help(zvau)`, I get the above documentation in R.

For 2), perhaps you are not exporting all "public" functions in your documentation?

Comment: amazing !! thanks 

last night I found this: http://stat545.com/packages04_foofactors-package-01.html

and it suggests the same